# Test Safe-Browsing using Selenium chromedriver in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, safe-browsing

Im trying to reach the famous safe browsing red error-page using selenium chromedriver with no success- tried every flag/pref that I could find...

Any suggestions/thoughts?

heres my code (python):

```
prefs = {"directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing": {"enabled": True, "malware": {"enabled": True}},
    "alternate_error_pages": True,
    "browser": {"safebrowsing": {"enabled": True, "malware":"enabled": True}}},
    }

exclude_default_swithes = ["disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
    "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update",
    "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection",
    "ignore-certificate-errors",]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", exclude_default_swithes)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, chrome_options=options, service_log_path=log_path)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u forgot to set a {} in l.4

```
prefs = {
    "directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing": {
        "enabled": True,
        "malware": {
            "enabled": True
            }
    },
    "alternate_error_pages": True,
    "browser": {
        "safebrowsing": {
            "enabled": True,
            "malware":{
                "enabled": True
                }
            }
        }
    },
}

exclude_default_swithes = ["disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
    "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update",
    "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection",
    "ignore-certificate-errors",]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", exclude_default_swithes)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, chrome_options=options, service_log_path=log_path)
```